# Why does (*Client) Do() from net/http return error instead of *url.Error?

Tags: go, net-http

The documentation for the Do method of the http client of net/http in Golang says that “Any returned error will be of type *url.Error.” Why is the return type error then? Doesn’t this just require users to do a type check to get information from the underlying error that is guaranteed to always be there?

Comment: Because all errors returned in Go are of type error.

Comment: Right, but this method doesn’t return any general error, it only returns *url.Error.

Comment: (1) consistency as pointed out by Volker (2) avoids introducing [nil error value not equal to nil](https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error) (3) it's rare users do a tpe check to get the underlying error from this method.

Comment: I guess point #2 is the most important. If you assign the concrete type to an error interface, the result is never nil. It’s only nil if the function returns a nil interface value directly. Otherwise you would always have to match on the contained value to know if it was nil or not.

Comment: No, the main reason is #1.

Comment: `error` is an interface in Go. You can create your own struct and by implementing the method `Error() string` of the `error` interface for your struct you can create your own error which can be returned as type `error` too. In general as people above mentioned in Go all errors are of type `error`.

Comment: @Volker So I understand that there is a convention to return "error" from methods rather than concrete structures. I'm just trying to understand the reasoning behind that. See https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/m3ka0h/comment/gqpkl5r/ for someone who is asking the same question. If it really just a matter of "either way would work, but we as a community agree to do it this way because of convention" I think that is also a reasonable outcome, just one that I don't fully grok the reasoning behind.

Comment: It's not simply a "convention". The reason is dead simple: It's much more sensible to hava common interface than individual types, especially if you ever want to _implement_ an interface and suddenly your method simply **cannot** return concrete error types. And using io.Error as is was 15 years ago is even less good. Maybe just stop thinking about it for a while. It's so _obvious_ that if you don't see it thinking about it probably doesn't help much.

Comment: Maybe just try it out and use concrete types as erros in a large project. This is the best way to learn about reasons. Peter already explained all this in the Reddit thread and linked an answer. Really: Maybe just accept it until you understand it. (Or try working with erros and interface methods that may fail and you'll see yourself.)